# Watson Assistant Maximum dialog_nodes limit exceeded (100 nodes)

Tags: limit, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I'm using Watson Assistant to create a chatbot. I am currently having the Lite plan.

In the dialog of skill I'm now facing the following error:

> Unable to add a node. Error: Maximum dialog_nodes limit exceeded. Limit
>   = 100.

What is the limit of the number of nodes in the standard plan (or plus or premium)? Being able to have only 100 nodes in a dialog is terrible.

Moreover, I have a pretty strict flow, that means a dialog tree with small width but huge depth (basically only one big branch). What is the limit of tree depth for the different plans? It is not mentioned in the pricing. Will I face problems with a large tree depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the IBM Cloud Docs, Lite plan supports 100 nodes per skill and Standard/Premium/Plus plans support 100,000 nodes per skill

> Tree depth limit: The service supports 2,000 dialog node descendants;
>   the tool performs best with 20 or fewer.
>
> The limits changed from 25,000 to 100 for Lite plans on 1 December
>   2018. Users of service instances that were created before the limit changed have until 1 June 2019 to upgrade their plan or edit the
>   dialogs in the skills in the existing service instances to meet the
>   new limit requirements.

For more details on the dialog nodes limit for each plan, refer to this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-build.html#dialog-build)